# LOG4J 2 no me escribe log

Tags: java, aplicación-web, java-ee, log4j2

tengo un problema con log4j2, a continuación paso a detallar el problema según los pasos que he ido dando:

1. Cargo las **librerías** en el proyecto:

log4j-api2.22.1.jar y log4j-impl2.22.1.jar

2. Cargo **fichero de configuración** en WEB-INF
   log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">file://C:/temp/logs</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger"
            fileName="${basePath}/app.log"
            filePattern="${basePath}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
            </Policies>
            <!-- Max 10 files will be created everyday -->
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10">
                <Delete basePath="${basePathr}" maxDepth="10">
                    <!-- Delete all files older than 30 days -->
                    <IfLastModified age="30d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL" additivity="false" >
            <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" />
        </Root>
        <logger name="app" level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="fileLogger"/>
        </logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

3. En el listener del programa cargo el xml

```
...
@Override
    public void contextInitialized( ServletContextEvent arg0 ) {

    
        ServletContext context = arg0.getServletContext();
        Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ConnectionListener.class);
        System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", context.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/")+"log4j2.xml" );
        
        System.out.println("Configuration File Defined To Be :: "+System.getProperty("log4j.configurationFile"));
...
LOGGER.trace( "Arrancando servicio de conexion.........................................." );
...
```

3. Inicio programa normalmente
4. **El programa escribe en consola:**

```
* INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio [Catalina]
*feb 09, 2024 10:42:42 A. M. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
*INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache* Tomcat/10.1.17]
*feb 09, 2024 10:42:44 A. M. org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
*INFORMACIÓN: Al menos un JAR, que se ha explorado buscando TLDs, aún no contenía TLDs. *Activar historial de depuración para este historiador para una completa lista de los JARs que fueron explorados y de los que nos se halló TLDs. Saltarse JARs no necesarios durante la exploración puede dar lugar a una mejora de tiempo significativa en el arranque y compilación de JSP .
*Configuration File Defined To Be :: C:\apache-tomcat-10.1.17\wtpwebapps\HospitalSP\WEB-INF\log4j2.xml
*File Directory created to be used for storing files
*Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
*feb 09, 2024 10:42:44 A. M. org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
*INFORMACIÓN: Desplegando el directorio [C:\apache-tomcat-10.1.17\webapps\docs] de la aplicación web
*feb 09, 2024 10:42:44 A. M. org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
*INFORMACIÓN: Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.1.17\webapps\docs] has finished in [26] ms
*feb 09, 2024 10:42:44 A. M. org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
*INFORMACIÓN: Desplegando el directorio [C:\apache-tomcat-10.1.17\webapps\examples] de la aplicación web
*feb 09, 2024 10:42:45 A. M. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
*INFORMACIÓN: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
*feb 09, 2024 10:42:45 A. M. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

4. **Reviso logs y no ha escrito nada**

**¿Que esta mal?, ¿la configuración?**,

Answer (score 0):

Añado un listener en  web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.infrastructure.servicepack.connection.Log4jInitializer</listener-class>
</listener>
```

el código del listener es:

```
package com.infrastructure.servicepack.connection;


import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class Log4jInitializer implements ServletContextListener {
    
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Get the servlet context
        ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();

        // Convert the file path to a URI and obtain the real path
        String log4jConfigLocation = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml");
        if (log4jConfigLocation != null) {
            log4jConfigLocation = "file:///" + log4jConfigLocation.replace("\\", "/");
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the real path is not available
            System.err.println("Unable to locate log4j2.xml file.");
            return;
        }

        // Initialize Log4j2
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        context.setConfigLocation(URI.create(log4jConfigLocation));
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        // Shutdown Log4j2
        LogManager.shutdown();
    }
}
```

***Con esto funciona por fin***